# Question about random variable X. (Distance of chosen number from 0)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

From interval $[-3,5)$ we draw 1 number, let the random variable $X$ be distance of chosen number from 0.

$$
P(A)=\frac{\lambda(A)) }{8}
$$

$$
X(x)=|x|
$$

It's an example task sent to us by professor, I have to do similar exercises to this but I can't even understand how he got following equations

$$
t<0, F(t)=P(X\leq t) = P(x:X(x)\leq t)=P(\emptyset)=0
$$

$$
t\in [0,3), F(t)=P(X\leq t) = P(x:X(x)\leq t)=P([-t,t])= \frac{2t}{8}
$$

$$
t\in [3,5), F(t)=P(X\leq t) = P(x:X(x)\leq t)=P([-3,t])= \frac{t+3}{8}
$$

$$
t\geq 5, F(t)=P(X\leq t) = P(x:X(x)\leq t)=P([-3,5])= 1
$$

We are behind in material because of quarantine, am I supposed to know what's going on in this part?
I feel like it's just solution without steps on how it's done.

Could someone explain for example how $\frac{2t}{8}$ was calculated?

Comment: what is $\lambda$? Is it Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Exodd Not sure, what I wrote is what we got. 
Its first task from Continuous random variable, we are supposed to learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lambda$ is apparently the Lebesgue measure, i.e. $\lambda(A)$ is the length of $A$ if $A$ is an interval.

I'll do $t \in [0,3)$. The event $\{X \leq t\}$ says that the number you draw uniformly from $[-3,5]$ should have absolute value at most $t$ (i.e. distance from 0 is at most $t$). This means that the number must come from $[-t,t]$.

Then the question is: what is the probability that a number you pick uniformly from $[-3,5]$ will come from $[-t,t]$? This is just the length of the interval $[-t,t]$ (which is $2t$) divided by the length of $[-3,5]$ (which is 8).

Try to apply the same idea to $t \in [-3,5)$. Again, you want to find the probability that the number you pick will be at most $t$ in absolute value. Where should it come from?